# PushSharp 4.0 Performance Issue

Tags: pushsharp

I m trying to push more than 500 K GCM and APNS notification, but it takes even more than 10 minutes in v4.0 while  v2.0  takes 2-3 minutes over all.
I tried to change scale up to 50 or keep it 10 and increase the thread - task count but could not decrease the time elapsed.

My code similar in [PushSarp git documentation](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/tree/4.0.4)

Application is run on 8 Gb ram, 2.3 Ghz cpu server.
Do you have any suggestions ?
Thank you!